# jQuery Plugin Function return a value

Tags: validation, jquery-plugins, return-value

I am writing a jquery form validation plugin, its working fine. I am passing a form ID with its input types, something like this :

`$('#contactForm :input').validateForm();`

And inside my plugin I have following code :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.validateForm = function() {
        var values = new Array();
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            if($(this).hasClass('required'))
            {
                if($(this).hasClass('number'))
                {
                    number = $(this).val();
                    if(number == '' || number.length < 9 || number.length > 13 || isNaN(number))
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('error');
                    }

                }else{

                    return true;

                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now my problem is that I want my plugin to return a value as true or false. If the form is validated then it should return true or if not then false.

I want to achieve something like this

```
val = $('#contactForm :input').validateForm();
if(val){
   //DO AJAX
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.validateForm = function() {
        var values = new Array();
        var isOK = true; /* Form is OK unless we detect an error */
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            if($(this).hasClass('required'))
            {
                if($(this).hasClass('number'))
                {
                    number = $(this).val();
                    if(number == '' || number.length < 9 || number.length > 13 || isNaN(number))
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('error');
                        isOK = false; /* Remember that error was detected */
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        return isOK; /* let caller know if error was detected */
    }
});
```